# Android app signing for Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to use only the previous password used to sign an APK when signing a new APK, or is a keystore file a necessity?

A bit more info:
We have an Android App uploaded to Google Play. Our previous Android developer has left us, and he's given us the password used to sign the apk file uploaded to google play. 
Our new Android developer is saying that he must be provided a "keystore file", and the password is not enough.

We're stuck between two developers, please help!

Comment: You need the old keystore otherwise you aren't able to update, so you can only upload a new app with a different package name

Comment: So the password is not enough to generate the same keystore? If it matters, the old developer was using Eclipse.

Comment: No unfortunately it isn't. You need the file